# giving each attachment a title

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm looking to add a title/name to each uploaded item with Fineuploader. 
Each attachment would show a textbox next to it so the user could enter the title/name before pressing 'Upload' [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOw9O.png)

I've had a look and each upload request sends something like

```
fine.uploader.php?qquuid=f5ff0211-c004-4b1d-8ea7-228d49c4a694&qqtotalfilesize=54&qqfile=DrayTek.txt
```

If I could get it to add '&title' to this - I have PHP to handle any 'GETs' on the fine.uploader.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
  element: $('#manual-fine-uploader')[0],
  request: {
    endpoint: 'fine.uploader.php?parent_type=<?php echo $parent_type; ?>&parent_id=<?php echo $parent_id; ?>&initial=<?php echo $initial; ?>&view=<?php echo $view; ?>&crm_user=<?php echo $crm_user; ?>'
  },
  autoUpload: false,
  text: {
    uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Attachments'
  }
});

$('#triggerUpload').click(function() {
  manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the `setParams` method. This will add the parameters set within to your request.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#manual-fine-uploader')[0],
        request: {
            endpoint: 'fine.uploader.php'
        },
        autoUpload: false,
        text: {
            uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Attachments'
        }
    });

    $('#triggerUpload').click(function() {

        manualuploader.setParams({
            parent_type: <?php echo $parent_type; ?>, // I am assuming that these are integer values that do not need quotes around them
            parent_id: <?php echo $parent_id; ?>,
            initial: <?php echo $initial; ?>,
            view: <?php echo $view; ?>,
            crm_user: <?php echo $crm_user; ?>
        });

        manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
});
```

Comment: still none the wiser - where does the input box go? Tried your code in my script and it wouldnt upload any files.

Comment: yes worked great thanks! I got the value from a text box using this code `manualuploader.setParams({
            test: document.getElementById('id').value
        });`. Now I need to get it to distinguish between separate upload instances and their relevant text boxes...

Comment: @AndyKarczewski That's good news. Don't forget to mark the correct answer so the whole SO community can benefit.